# Existing Datamap for TYPO3 to Joomla?

Tags: c#, mysql, joomla, typo3

I'm looking for an existing datamap and/or MySQL script that can migrate data between TYPO3 and Joomla. Obviously, both CMS use MySQL and that's great, but I'm wondering if there is already a document/script that takes the elements from TYPO3 database and puts them in the Joomla database.

I'm planning to write my own migration program in C# so if anyone has some code snippets for that, it would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget that, there are too many differences to make it possible... TYPO3 instances are built typically with many various extension + pages + content elements etc. Although Joomla's initial structure is quite simple (as far as I remember) when you are adding new plugins it changes in many different ways. Conclusion is simple if somebody wrote such 'mapper' between *his* TYPO3 and *his* Joomla most probably will not work in any other combination.

How many pages are there in the TYPO3 ? if less than 100 I wouldn't waste a time for any programm, just copy/paste it in common editing mode.

If more, I think that would be best solution to write a TYPO3 extension (PHP), which will get all required data from some page using it's parsers, configs etc and will convert it to JSON (or even pure SQL insert statements) with structure understandable in Joomla. Keep in mind that many elements can be quite different in the database - than on the client's side. The best example are internal links which in DB are saved just as ID's of pages to which they are pointing. You need to resolve it on the TYPO3 side, or you'll need to learn how relations are built in TYPO3's database to do the same task in your C# application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is definitely a dearth of information on the web for this type of migration so that certainly indicates a lot of difficulty with it . . .

Comment: Apparently I wrote it unclear, so I'll repeat: you will not find direct tool/description for 99.999999999% The only way is learn both structures and prepare the exporter on the TYPO3 side, to include all configs, parsers, etc. Suicidal task for person without TYPO3 knowledge. Using C# for this task is like a brain transplant between two species sitting in another room... All I can in this place is just wish you luck.

Comment: :) that wasn't agresive, believe me